# The splinter Browser in Python cannot work

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

This is the sample code:

> > from splinter import Browser
> >
> > b = Browser()

However I got the error as below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the last line of the error it appears that 'geckodriver' needs to be added to your PATH.